# Проблема с вызовом метода

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не работают два метода .fill_field() и .draw_field()

```
function cell_state() {
    this.is_mine = false;
    this.is_open = false;
    this.mine_around = 0;
  }
var game = {
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
  mine_count: 10,
  open_count: 0,
  field: [],
  fill_field: function () {
    for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
        game.field.push(new cell_state());
       }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < game.mine_count; i++) {     
      var xx = Math.floor(Math.random * game.width);
      var yy = Math.floor(Math.random * game.height);
      if (!game.field[xx][yy].is_mine) {
        game.field[xx][yy].is_mine = true;
      } else {
        i--;
      }
    }
  },
  draw_field: function() {
  $("body").append("<table>");
  for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
   $("table").append("<tr>");
   for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
  $("tr").append("<td>");
}
}
}
};
game.fill_field();
game.draw_field();
```

Comment: Что значит `не работает`?

Comment: действительно не работает?

Comment: Когда я вызываю эти методы они не делают того, что должны делать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function cell_state() {
  this.is_mine = false;
  this.is_open = false;
  this.mine_around = 0;
}
var game = {
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
  mine_count: 10,
  open_count: 0,
  field: [],
  fill_field() {
    for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
      // 1: У вас дальше в коде идёт обращение таким образом: game.field[xx][yy]
      // А field вы делаете одномерным массивом. Тут надо создавать массив-столбец:
      var row = [];
      game.field.push(row);
      for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
        // И клетки класть в него, а не прямо в field
        row.push(new cell_state());
      }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < game.mine_count; i++) {     
     // 2: Math.random это функция (скобки забыли)
      var xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.width);
      var yy = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.height);
      if (!game.field[xx][yy].is_mine) {
        game.field[xx][yy].is_mine = true;
      } else {
        i--;
      }
    }
  },
  draw_field: function() {
    $("body").append("<table>");
    for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
     $("table").append("<tr>");
     for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
        // 3: Какую именно строку таблицы вы тут получаете?
        // $("tr").append("<td>"); 
        // Вам нужна последняя:
        $("tr:last-child").append(`<td class="${game.field[x][y].is_mine?'ismine':''}">`); 
      }
    }
  }
};
game.fill_field();
game.draw_field();
```

```css
td{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td.ismine{
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: в строке $("tr:last-child").append(`<td class="${game.field[x][y].is_mine?'ismine':''}"> вы использовали регулярные выражения?

Comment: @FischerBenkovscki Это не регулярное выражение, это [шаблонная строка](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-string#%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B)

Примерно то же самое, что `'<td class="' + game.field[x][y].is_mine ? 'ismine' : '' + '">'`

Comment: Спасибо! ВЫ мне очень помогли